# To find the common values between the arrays and also need to find the count

Tags: c, arrays, string

I've made a program that finds the values that are contained in both arrays and also the count of those values, but my program doesn't work:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define SIZE 100
void search(char arr1[10][10],char arr2[10][10])
    {       //int x = sizeof(arr1); int y = sizeof(arr2)
        int j,k;
            for( j=0;j<SIZE-1;j++)
            {   
                for( k=0;k<SIZE-1;k++)
                {   int count = 0;
                    if(arr1[j][0] == arr2[k][0])
                    {
                        count += 1;
                    }

                }
                return count;   
            printf("StudentID\t : BooksTanken\t\n");
                    printf("%c \t\t %d \t\n",arr1[j][0],count); }
    }
int main()
{
//  char array1[2][1],array2[5][1];
    char  array1[3][2]={
                                    {'ID1','srini'},
                                    {'ID2','Albie'},
                                    {'ID3','Kaasi'}};
            char array2[6][2]={
                                    {'ID1','OOPS'},
                                    {'ID2','STS'},
                                    {'ID1','STS'},
                                    {'ID1','CTC'},
                                    {'ID3','MAT'},
                                    {'ID2','MAT'}};
    printf("We're Begining the Comaprison Here !!\n\n");

    search(array1,array2);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: /*From the Above ive find the Person name and how many books he taken?*/

Comment: the code in your question has so many compiling errors that makes it difficult to answer it in a concise way. you should instead read up on basic C programming before posting and then try to keep your questions very specific. e.g. 'ID1' is not what you think it is

Answer (score 3):

You need to read up on strings in C. This should be expressed as strings, and you should use e.g. `strcmp()` to do the comparison, not a manual loop. You would also benefit hugely from learning about `struct`s, and using arrays of such rather than bare arrays of characters.

Comment: Even Though i'm converting from char to string compiler doesn't recognising it

Answer (score 3):

snippets:

```
#define SIZE 100
void search(char arr1[10][10],char arr2[10][10])
....
           for( j=0;j<SIZE-1;j++)

....
char  array1[3][2]={
```

do you see the discrepancies?
100, 10, 3

EDITH: to show you the problem:

```
for (i < 0; i < SIZE-1; i++) {
   arr[i] = 0;
}
```

may be expanded by the compiler to:

```
arr[0] = 0;
arr[1] = 0;
arr[2] = 0;
arr[3] = 0;
arr[4] = 0;
arr[5] = 0;
arr[6] = 0;
arr[7] = 0;
```

...
    arr[98] = 0;

your array has only memory allocated for arr[0], arr[1], arr[2]; so referencing arr[3] may be a bad thing to do...

EDITH 2: Question: why 'SIZE-1'?

Comment: I agree with you peter but certainly i declared the SIZE 100 for future case if the array size might be bigger the program must to function .

Comment: hmmm, let me be sceptical: you have an array of 3by 2 elements, but iterate over 100 elemnts in this array. This can only lead to erroros.